# including files problem

Tags: c++, include

I have `test.h` file and `example.h` file and I want to include each one in the other 
I tried the following but didn't work.

In file test.h:

```
 #ifndef "example.h"

 #define "example.h"`

...

 #endif
```

And in file example.h :

```
#include "test.h"
```

And later tried :

```
#ifndef "test.h"

 #define "test.h"

...

#endif
```

But nothing worked.

Comment: "It didn't work" - well, I guess there's nothing to be done.  Unless you can tell us WHAT didn't work, what you tried, specific messages you get, etc.

Comment: Hi Katia.  Define what you mean by "doesn't work".  Circular dependency like this is usually a design error.  You might want to show the contents of the files and we can make some suggestions.

Comment: @Joe I get this error "fatal error C1016: #if[n]def expected an identifier"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to come up with some unique identifiers for each include guard. For example:

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H
...
#endif
```

You can't just use the filenames with #ifndef etc.

Comment: tried it and it stopped giving me error about including part .. thanks alot

Comment: It is possible that you might find two include files with the same name.  (e.g. one might be in a library so you don't know about it) To avoid having two files with "`#define EXAMPLE_H`", I sometimes use a unique idenifier like a GUID.  e.g. "`#define EXAMPLE_H_B09BD769_5844_11E0_A3B6_6CF0494804C2`"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should write like below:

In file test.h:

```
#ifndef __TEST_H__
#define __TEST_H__
#include "example.h"
#endif// __TEST_H__
```

In file example.h:

```
#ifndef __EXAMPLE_H__
#define __EXAMPLE_H__
#include "test.h"
#endif//__EXAMPLE_H__
```

Comment: It's bad practice to prefix `#define`s with two underscores.  If you really need to make it something unique, use the full path of the file, the date and time, a randomly-generated string, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. This way goes to circular include hell. Resolve your problem by defining structures you use

example.h

```
class bar;

    class foo
    {
        bar* barPtr;
    }
```

test.h

```
class foo;

class bar 
{
    foo* fooPtr;
}
```

Comment: that's what we're doing actually .. I made a class .h and .cpp and other team mate did an other one . now my functions need to use object of the other class and vice versa.. that what caused the circle in the first place

Comment: your problem is not going to be solved by #ifdef's. Try to move common structures in a 3rd header and include that in both projects, or apply solution described above.